# Sound proofing wall in living room

Tags: sound-proofing

I live in the top floor of a wood frame condo with high ceiling. Lately, my downstairs neighbor has been playing loud music with bass in their living room and I can hear the music and feel the bass on the floor. How can I sound proof the room? It is the wall right behind the TV area. Can I hang a rug or curtain on the wall and it will decrease the noise?

Update: will hanging sound panels on the wall work? How about adding brick veneer? With the strata bylaws, I can't alter the wall as it is a part of the building structure but I can decorate it.

Comment: The answer depends a great deal on how much time and money you're willing to invest.

Comment: Insulating against low frequencies can be tough. The structure will tend to resonate, so any soundproofing you add won't be terribly effective.

Comment: If you can “feel the bass” you have a big problem, that is going to be difficult, if not impossible, to remediate with soundproofing techniques.   “Condo” implies ownership of your unit, you may find the answer in your tenants association’s rules.  But that angle is off-topic here......

Comment: What has your wall in your TV area got to do with you feeling bass in the floor?

Comment: @AndyT the downstairs neighbor floor layout is similar to mine; their tv/home entertainment setup is in the same area and probably has their speakers right against the wall. When they play loud music or music with bass, I can hear and feel the vibration from the wall as well as from the floor. The apartments below have low ceiling. I can actually feel my floor vibrate when the neighbor jump/run around in their flat.

Comment: There's a proposed edit from an anonymous poster.  Looks like it is probably you.  You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, it must be done under the user account that posted it.  If you don't log in before trying to edit, it goes to a review queue to make sure somebody isn't doing something detrimental.

Comment: If it is upstairs vs. downstairs, that wall won't make a difference.  It isn't what's transferring the sound.  Sound panels won't help.  They absorb high frequency sound and what is coming through is mostly low frequencies.  You can improve it a little by putting down large rugs over thick padding.  But the biggest improvement will come from explaining to your neighbor how the sound travels to your apartment and is loud enough to be bothersome, and ask them to use some moderation.  They may be unaware that the building sucks as far as sound isolation.

Answer (score 1):

For base you need lots of solid materials like extra layers of drywall and sound breaks. Carpets and insulation won’t cut it. Softer materials have a little effect on higher frequencies. I built a sound studio with a lot of thought and planning going into sound bleeding into other rooms. We were able to reduce the base but not eliminate it. For a home, there is not much you can do.